# Connection Pooling in SQL Azure

Tags: web-config, connection-pooling, azure-sql-database

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC app. This app is relying on data stored in a SQL Azure database. When I logged into the SQL Azure management interface, I notice that I had 17 active connections to my database. I vaguely remember the concept of database connection pooling from long ago. For some reason, I thought to use connection pooling, you needed to add a setting to your connection string in your web.config file. For the life of me though, I can't remember or find documentation on a setting.

For reference sake, I'm using System.Data.SqlClient as the provide in my connection string settings. Can someone please tell me how to use connection pooling in SQL Azure? Considering I'm the only one hitting the database, 17 active connections seemed high. I figured if connection pooling was turned on, only 1 active connection should appear.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Connection pooling is a default behavior that cannot be configured by the client for Sql Azure. Your app should be getting the benefits of connection pooling by default. Ensure that your connections strings are unique as a new pool will be created for connections with different strings. [This article in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) specifies:

> When a new connection is opened, if the connection string is not an
>   exact match to an existing pool, a new pool is created. Connections
>   are pooled per process, per application domain, per connection string
>   and when integrated security is used, per Windows identity. Connection
>   strings must also be an exact match; keywords supplied in a different
>   order for the same connection will be pooled separately.

Now with regards to a setting that you don't remember. You may have been talking about [MARS (Multiple Active Result Sets).](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/multiple-active-result-sets-mars) This feature is [now available](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlazure/archive/2010/04/16/9997517.aspx) on Sql Azure.

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest you to read the following article which explains how to correctly design a connection to SQL Azure and it also have a C# base sample code to show you how:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlazure/archive/2010/05/11/10011247.aspx

Comment: Link is dead, and no relevant parts were included in the answer